# Select from table with optional values

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select

I have a PostgreSQL with two tables: Person & Address.

The table person has a foreign key referencing Address table, but this field is optional (NULL by default), so a "Person" is not required to have an "Address".

I want to get (with a SELECT query) all the registries of Person, regardless if they have an Address or not. How can I do it in a single query?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Person p LEFT JOIN Address a ON p.<col_name> = a.<col_name>` When you don't have corresponding value in second table use `OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a LEFT [JOIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-join.html), which returns all rows from the first table, regardless of whether or not a matching row is found in the joined table.

See also: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

```
SELECT *
    FROM Person p
        LEFT JOIN Address a
            ON p.Address_ID = a.Address_ID
```

Comment: Thanks both guys ^^. I used to make joins manually in WHERE clause and I did not realize to use this.

Comment: @malkomich The implicit join syntax that you mention is not ANSI standard and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Try use a left join, like this:

```
select * from table1 left join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```